# Maximum Report Processing has been reached for crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, report, max, limit, dispose

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Web.Security;
    using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
    using System.Drawing.Imaging;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Xml;
    using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;

    using CrystalDecisions.ReportSource;
    using CrystalDecisions.Reporting;
    using CrystalDecisions.Shared;
    using CrystalDecisions.Web;


        public partial class Schools : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            ReportDocument crystalReport = new ReportDocument();

            protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!Page.IsPostBack)
                {
                    try
                    {

                        string query = "select * from School Where Designation = 'Public' Order by School ASC";

                        crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath("ReportPrimary.rpt"));


                        MPrimary dsCustomers = GetData(query);
                        crystalReport.SetDataSource(dsCustomers);

                        crystalReport.SetDatabaseLogon("username", "password.34", "mssql.webaddress.net,4118", "dataDB");

                        SchReport.ReportSource = crystalReport;

                        Session["ReportDocument"] = crystalReport;
                    }
                    catch (LogOnException ex)
                    {
        //Throws an exception if an error is encountered on retrieval
                    }


                }
                else
                {


                     string query = "select * from School Where Designation = " + "'" + drpSchoolDesignation.SelectedValue + "'" + " Order by School ASC";

                    //    ReportDocument crystalReport = new ReportDocument();
                    crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath("ReportPrimary.rpt"));


                    TextObject to = (TextObject)crystalReport.ReportDefinition.Sections["Section2"].ReportObjects["Text3"];
                    to.Text = drpSchoolDesignation.SelectedValue.ToUpper() + " SCHOOLS";

                    MPrimary dsCustomers = GetData(query);
                    crystalReport.SetDataSource(dsCustomers);
                    SchReport.FindControl("Text3");

                    crystalReport.SetDatabaseLogon("username", "password.34", "mssql.webaddress.net,4118", "dataDB");


                    ReportDocument doc = (ReportDocument)Session["ReportDocument"];
                    SchReport.ReportSource = doc;

                }

            }
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }
            private void OpenNewWindow(string url, string windowName, string windowParams)
            {
                if (url == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("url");
                if (windowName == null)
                    windowName = "";
                if (windowParams == null)
                    windowParams = "";
                string scriptCode =
                    string.Format(
                        "<script>window.open('{0}','{1}','{2}');</script>",
                        url, windowName, windowParams);
                //write the script out to HTTP Response stream
                Response.Write(scriptCode);
            }
            private MPrimary GetData(string query)
            {
                string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;

                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        using (MPrimary dsCustomers = new MPrimary())
                        {
                            sda.Fill(dsCustomers, "School");
                            return dsCustomers;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            protected void drpSchoolDesignation_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                drpDisplay.SelectedIndex = 0;
                drpSort.SelectedIndex = 0;


                string   query = "select * from School Where Designation = " + "'" + drpSchoolDesignation.SelectedValue + "'" + " Order by School ASC";


                crystalReport.Load(Server.MapPath("ReportPrimary.rpt"));

                TextObject to = (TextObject)crystalReport.ReportDefinition.Sections["Section2"].ReportObjects["Text3"];
                to.Text = drpSchoolDesignation.SelectedValue.ToUpper() + " SCHOOLS";

                MPrimary dsCustomers = GetData(query);
                crystalReport.SetDataSource(dsCustomers);

                crystalReport.SetDatabaseLogon("username", "password.34", "mssql.webaddress.net,4118", "dataDB");

                Session["ReportDocument"] = crystalReport;
                SchReport.ReportSource = crystalReport;

            }
            protected void CrystalReportViewer1_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                crystalReport.Close();
                crystalReport.Dispose();
            }

            protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
        //Select data from DB
            //Action to be added later
            }


        }
```

This code is supposed to retrieve and display info using crystal reports.
    It seems my object is not been properly disposed. Modifying this code disables the user from ever getting to page 3 of the document. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks guys in advance.

Comment: Is the error in crystal reports or business objects

Comment: after running the code for awhile, it writes the maximum processing limit configured by the administrator has been reached.

Comment: Not sure about the C sharp code but normally this issue occurs when records that are read exceeds the system parameter value.. I observed this issue in CMC.. not sure about code